# Material-ui Autocomplete filtered list

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using material-ui autocomplete component when I'm typing I need the filtered list which is suggested to me, is there any event for these?

Comment: Let me understand better, you pass an array of values to autocomplete and if you type on textfield you want to filter that array based on what you wrote, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create two arrays state.

assuming an initial options list, like

```
const initialList = [
  {
    name: "item1",
  },
  {
    name: "item2",
  },
  {
    name: "item3",
  },
  {
    name: "item4",
  },
  {
    name: "item5",
  },
  {
    name: "item6",
  },
  {
    name: "item7",
  },
];
```

then, pass to useState,

```
const [itemList, setItemList] = useState(initialList);
const [itemSelected, setItemSelected] = useState([]);

const handleChange = () => (event, value) => {
   setItemSelected(value);
}


<Autocomplete
            multiple
            id='items-outlined'
            value={itemSelected}
            options={itemList}
            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
            getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option.name === value.name}
            onChange={handleChange()}
            filterSelectedOptions
            fullWidth
            renderInput={(params) => (
              <TextField
                {...params}
                variant='outlined'
                label='Items'
                placeholder='Select items...'
                fullWidth
                InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
              />
            )}
          />
```

I'm using it in my projects